# Does az vmss run-command run concurrently across all instances when ran?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am currently trying to enable TLS 1.2 across all of the instances in an Azure VM scale set. I would like to leverage Az CLI's **az vmss run-command invoke** to do this but could not find whether or not it would hit all of the instances at the same time. Part of the powershell script that I am passing to the command involves restarting the instance and I would like to prevent most of the instances being restarted at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [az vmss run-command invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vmss_run_command_invoke), you can execute a specific run command on a Virtual Machine Scale Set instance with parameter `--instance-id`. So you can manually specify on which instance will execute the scripts.

For example, you can install Nginx on a VMSS instance.

```
 az vmss run-command invoke -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVMSS --command-id RunShellScript \ --instance-id 0 --scripts "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nginx"
```

Comment: Hey Nancy, thanks for the reply. That's actually the method I'm using now to hit each instance individually. I was trying to see if I could leverage az cli's ability to hit every instance in one go but didn't want to bring down the scale set by restarting everything at once (as part of the script I'm pushing involves a restart).

Comment: You could use [az vmss extension set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss/extension?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vmss_extension_set) to run a custom extension script on vmss in one go and you can schedule the reboot using a Windows Scheduled Task , or use tools such as DSC, Chef, or Puppet extensions. Read the [Tips and Tricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#tips-and-tricks).

Comment: @NancyXiong ,I would like to run shell commands in all VMSS instances during provisioning of VMSS via terraform script. how could we do that?